# javascript concat string to object

Tags: javascript, object

Please check code below. Here all variable values are static.

`var o = { level_a:{}, level_b:{}, . . . .};`

`var levelVar = "b";`

`var selected_tab = 'level'+'_'+levelVar; \\level_b`

`var result = o.selected_tab;`

Here you can see `var o` is object and `var levelVar` and `selected_tab` are string. Now I expect I should get value of `o.level_b` inside `result`, but its not working becuse we can not concat string to object.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this notation :

```
result = o[selected_tab];
```

More generally, when you have var `obj={a:'b'}`, you can access the property `a` using both `obj.a` and `obj['a']`.

Here's [a MDN reference about the use of objects and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: I am so fool . .. never thought in that way . . .anyways thanks !

Comment: don't forget to check with o.hasOwnProperty(selected_tab) to avoid erros ;)